# Context from 'views.py' not showing on 'base.html' - Django

Tags: python, django

I can't find where is the problem, so I want to create li element for each of my categories. Here are my codes:

views.py:

```
def categories(request):
    context = {
        'category_list':  Category.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

base.html:

```
<nav id="header-nav">
<ul id="nav-ul" class="menu font-reg clearfix">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
<a href="">Blog<span class="sub-drop-icon fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu sub-menu-first">
{% for category in category_list %}
<li><a href="#">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
<a href="about-1.html">About</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
<a href="contact-1.html">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('article/<slug:article_slug>', views.article, name='article'),
]
```

Category class:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: Are there some `Category`s in your database?

Comment: Yes, man @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Can you share your urls and your category model?

Comment: alright, @IainShelvington

Comment: It seems that you should call views.categories instead of views.article

Comment: still not working, man @chem1st

Comment: please, help me, @IainShelvington

Comment: what happened, @WillemVanOnsem ?

Comment: give me a hand, @chem1st

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the article and categories on the same page, you can do as follows:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('article/<slug:article_slug>', views.article, name='article'),
]
```

models.py

It's better to put `def __str__` below all the fields.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

You need to pass the article and the categories in one view.

```
def article(request, slug):
    context = {
        'article': Article.objects.get(slug=slug),
        'category_list':  Category.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

base.html

To show a list of categories:

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Note:

It will have much more sense to create a separate `article.html` page with `{% extends 'base.html' %}` line in the beginning to render your article.
Moreover, pay attention to [Class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/) for simple rendering lists and detail info for instances of your Models.

Comment: You should accept the `article_slug` URL parameter in the `article` view as well, but it simply does not make much sense what is happening.

Comment: Because, I have article view too. So, I must create url for categories also ?

Comment: Do you need your categories to be on the separate page, not on the single article page?

Comment: I have a page, where exist navbar and article sections. In the navbar section I want to show names of my categories, and in sections articles